# Letter (alphabet) recognition gestures in libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx

How would i detect letters (alphabet) gestures with libgdx. When a user draws the letter "a" on the screen i want to know.
There is the GestureOverlay in android and a gesturebuilder tool but i dont think i can integrate this with libgdx? since if that overlay is over the game view it wont receive any events? 
I just need a way to record gestures then test for them without any UI , so just passing some points to a gesture detection engine which attempts to detect letters and returns any matches.
If there was a java library rather than android it would be better too since i can test on the desktop and use on other platforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end i used the [GestureOverlayView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/gesture/GestureOverlayView.html) , this sits over the top of the libgdx view and still allows touches on the view but also captures touch events and does the letter gesture matching from a file that can be made with a gesture builder program. 
I used this for testing and building gestures.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.davemac327.gesture.tool&hl=en

Its android only solution but this does what i need for now and the matching is accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Reading alphabet fom Gestures is going to be hard. Have you tried using a OCR library - e.g http://code.google.com/p/mezzofanti/?